# Field Visibility

Tags: account

I have an issue where the user should not be edit certain fields when he is different app. For example I have 2 apps called A and B the user have access both the Apps. But the user need edit few case record when he is in A app he only  should not be edit when he is in B App ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic Forms in Lightning App Builder and create 2 pages that you assign to the different apps. One where you have restricted the fields to read only.

Trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/convert-a-lightning-page-to-dynamic-forms/get-started-with-dynamic-forms

How to article: https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-dynamic-forms-overview-deep-dive-tutorial/